# How to analyze Java class files?

Tags: java, class, analytics, .class-file

I have a Java .class-file. Now I'd like to find out which methods an fields it provides to the outside world.

I'd like to get a list of all methods and fields plus their visibility. The output could be:

```
1) final static String CONST = "Test"
2) final public void print(String)
3) protected(com.stackoverflow.package) void pprint(String)
```

Comment: Have you tried Java Decompiler with Eclipse? try this - http://jd.benow.ca/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **javap**

```
javap DocFooter.class
```

To get the static final constants

```
javap -constants DocFooter.class
```

[Check this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html)

Comment: You have to pass -p to get the full list of methods.

Answer (score 2):

For every class with in the JVM there is object of the type Class. You can query on this object to get all the info on that particular class.

Class myClass = MyClass.class
Method method[] = myClass.getDeclaredMethods();

Refer to Java doc for further info,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

If you just want to look at the class content then there are editors like djCompiler etc which does a pretty good job.